# Duda con Datos Agrupados - Tabla de Frecuencias

Tags: excel-2013

Quería saber si existe una forma de obtener una lista de datos en excel si tengo una tabla de frecuencias, por ejemplo:

Tengo

```
Dato | Frec.
   1  |   3
   2  |   5
   3  |   2
```

Quiero

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
3
3
```

No se me ocurre ni conozco ninguna forma con Excel.

Saludos y de antemano muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No conozco una funcion en excel que haga eso, pero con una macro se podria resolver, aqui hay algo que quiza te pueda guiar.

https://analisisydecision.es/truco-excel-repetir-un-campo-a-partir-de-otro-que-define-el-numero-de-repeticiones/

Comment: Esto no se considera como una respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias, la macro me sirvió.